# Why doesn't this code in C# throw an error

Tags: c#

Ideally the variable `returnString` being local variable and not initialised wouldn't have been able to be used and there would have been compile time error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'returnString'

In fact, that's what I got in another context. Still it works. Why?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
     class a {
         public static string testMethod(){
             string returnString;
             try
             {
                 int a = 100;
                 int b = 0;
                 b = a / b;
                 returnString= Convert.ToString(a - b);
                 // return returnString;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                  return  returnString = Convert.ToString(ex);
                  //throw ex;
             }
             return returnString;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // a A = new a();
            Console.WriteLine(a.testMethod());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `a A = new a();` There's something called naming conventions...

Comment: You don't currently have a code path where `returnString` remains uninitialized.

Comment: Well @Thomas I was trying with not static as well as static methods. That's where that a A = new a(); came from. Anyways it was working fine in both the cases

Comment: In any case (static or not) it should have been `A a = new A();`

Comment: Sorry folks there was a misunderstanding on my part. The context in which I was getting an error had an 'if' block in 'try' without 'else' part. Hence the compiler was throwing an error as in the absence of 'else' and without the initialisation, it wouldn't have been able to return any value.

Comment: I've removed all tags but c# because I feel that this question has nothing to do with OOP

Answer (score 2):

Decompiling the code (use release mode) often helps in such situations. Here's the decompiled source generated by dotPeek:

```
public static string testMethod()
{
  try
  {
    int num1 = 100;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = num1 / num2;
    return Convert.ToString(num1 - num3);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return Convert.ToString((object) ex);
  }
}
```

As you can see, for the compiler there's no uninitialized variable. So why should it complain?

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler understands that it will be assigned later.

This does not compile, because it's possible that the variable is not assigned before returning it (if a == 2 for example):

```
    private string method(int a)
    {
        string result;

        if (a == 1)
        {
            result = "2334234";           
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me as if every path through the function returns an initialized variable. Either you successfully convert the division by zero, or as you will have an exception, you assign the variable the value of the exception. You are always going to have a properly assigned value and the compiler sees that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code either sets `returnString` if:

1. Code doesn't throw an exception before setting the `returnString` variable inside the `try/catch` block.
2. If the code in the `try` block throws an exception, `returnString` will be assigned.

Conclusion: there's no case where the `returnString` variable could be unassigned.